# Generate Bootstrap tooltip on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with a text and some words in the text can change dynamically. These words have an  element and should have a tooltip. When the user hovers the word (or I guess on a touch device clicks it), a tooltip should be generated using `generateSpecialMarkupElement($(element).text())`. Once the HTML has been rendered to the DOM another JavaScript function has to be called `replaceMarkupHTML()`.
I don't have control over these functions unfortunately.

Now I'm wondering if there is a simple way in bootstrap get this done. For instance a `before` event to run the first function and an `after` event to call the second one.

Here is a simple example text and simplified versions of the functions:
http://jsfiddle.net/8aqz5auk/1/

So is there a bootstrap-way of hooking/intercepting this kind of thing? Or is there maybe another simple way it could be done?

**Edit**: I just had an idea. When bootstrap shows a tooltip, it seems to inject an element into the DOM. The interesting part is the container with the class 'tooltip-inner'. So I tried to listen on the body for new elements matching '.tooltip-inner' to be injected and whenever that happens I try to manipulate it:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.tooltip-inner', function () {
      var el = $(this)
      el.html("") // empty the tooltip element
      el.append(generateSpecialMarkupElement(el.text())) // insert the generated markup element
      replaceMarkupHTML() // replace the markup element with normal html
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. It just throws a a million errors and the site freezes when I try it.

**Edit 2**:
Thanks to Chris Barr, I got a little bit closer: http://jsfiddle.net/8aqz5auk/2/
But the tooltip doesn't always show up and the position of the tooltip seems to be kind of wrong (shows up on top of the word, rather then next to/above/below/...).

Comment: I don't really know if it's what you're asking for but... https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

Comment: It is not... at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the tooltip events listed in the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips-events

```
$('.elements-with-tooltips').on('show.bs.tooltip', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

You can run a function: before being shown, after being shown, before hiding, after hiding, and when the element is inserted into the DOM.

Comment: It seems to sort of work sometimes. But it is seems very unreliable. http://jsfiddle.net/8aqz5auk/2/ Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I think the issue is that you generate a tooltip, and then it attempts to position itself before it shows, and then right before that happens you're manually switching out the HTML inside the tooltip without the plugin knowing about it, and the position doesn't update.  What you've done technically works but it's ***very** hacky, especially since the tooltip can't be positioned correctly this way.  Also it appears your demo is using Bootstrap version 2.3.2, but version 3.3.7 is current - is this intentional?

Comment: Updating your demo to bootstrap 3.3.7 allows the use of the `inserted.bs.tooltip` event, which will allow the changes you require before the tooltip renders and is positioned.  Here's your demo cleaned up a bit, working as intended (but still **very hacky**!), and tiwh updated bootstrap. http://jsfiddle.net/8aqz5auk/4/

Comment: No that was not intentional. Thank you so much, it appears to work great!